# How to get the Pass and Fail count from html using powershell

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-3.0

Can someone help me how to get the pass and failed count from html file using powershell.

[html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icjrf.png)

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="project-name visible-md visible-lg">Protractor Test Execution Report</div>
          <div class="label-container">
            <span class="label label-success" title="TestCases">Passed: 1508</span>
            <span class="label label-danger" title="TestCases">Failed: 256</span> 
            
            <span class="label label-info">Time Elapsed: 10h 32min 26s</span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

or ,

I am trying to get value of FAILED in below line.
`Executed 336 of 336 specs[31m (10 FAILED)[39m in 1 hour 3 secs.` .
I have used below code
`$output='C:\Users\viuppulu\Desktop\consoloe.txt' $version = ($output | Select-String -Pattern "(?:\d+\FAILED)").Matches.Value`
but not working..
Can you please help to get FAILED value(10) and Executed value(336)

In the above Problem I am able to get the passed and Failed count. With the data I am creating one more html to make readable format. But how to get the data of Pass count and Fail count is 0 if failed is 0 or failed is not present on html.
[image: ORIGINAL HTML FILE WHERE I AM RETRIEVING THE DATA]
[image: READABLE FORMAT HTML FILE]

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="project-name visible-md visible-lg">Protractor Test Execution Report</div>
          <div class="label-container">
            <span class="label label-success" title="TestCases">Passed: 329</span>
            
            
            <span class="label label-info">Time Elapsed: 1h 24min 37s</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Maybe read up on things like [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1), [-match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#-match-and--notmatch) and [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: I haven't tried since i am new to Powershell.

Comment: @boxdog, can you please look into my second question and code which I tried. It would be great if you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question, parsing stuff from html using regex could be tricky, because browsers don't care if the lines are written neatly one after the other or not.

Anyway, you could try

```
$html = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\test.html' -Raw

$passed = $failed = 0
$regex = '<span class="label label-success"[^>]+>Passed: (\d+)</span>\s*<span class="label label-danger"[^>]+>Failed: (\d+)</span>'
if ($html -match $regex) {
    $passed = [int]$matches[1]
    $failed = [int]$matches[2]
}

$passed   # --> 1508
$failed   # -->  256
```

For your second question, you can do:

```
Select-String -Path 'C:\Users\viuppulu\Desktop\consoloe.txt' -Pattern 'Executed\s+(\d+).*(?:\((\d+) FAILED\))' | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'Executed'; Expression = { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }},
              @{Name = 'Failed'; Expression = { $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value }}
```

Output would be something like:

```
Executed Failed
-------- ------
336      10    
536      0     
136      7
```

---

As per your edited question, the span for Parsed or Failed might not be present in the html (I assumed they always were there..)

You can get both values like this:

```
$html = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\test.html' -Raw

$passed = $failed = 0
# test Passed and Failed separate. When 0 or not available, the resulting value is 0
if ($html -match '<span class="label label-success"[^>]+>Passed: (\d+)</span>') { $passed = [int]$matches[1] }
if ($html -match '<span class="label label-danger"[^>]+>Failed: (\d+)</span>')  { $failed = [int]$matches[1] }

# $passed  --> 329
# $failed  -->   0
```

Comment: Theo, Thanks for your inputs, I just slightly modified my code and it's working fine.

Comment: Theo, Can you please check my problem in original question

Comment: Theo, Thanks for the update, I have implemented same to my code, it is working fine if I get failed count is 0. But testing purpose I have used another file which contains pass and fail count like my initial question but I am getting failed count is zero even if file having failed count. Can you please suggest. I am looking for If my html file contains Pass: some number(1244),Failed(11), should display pass count(1244) and fail count(11) and if Pass:329 and failed:0, Should display pass count(329) and fail count(0) . I hope you got my question

Comment: Theo, I am sorry, it has mistake in my code. I just realized and modified same and it's working fine. Thank you